# UIBarButtonItem in custom UINavigationController not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

On my side menu I call a NavigationController for each item on didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Because of that I have a few NavigationControllers. So I created a custom UINavigationController to reuse the code.

The thing is that my UINavigationController subclass is being called but nothing appears on the simulator.

```
[self.sideMenuViewController setContentViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EventsXib"]];
```

EventsXib is my CustomNavigationController

Any idea?

For the record, the whole point for me to do this is that I want the same leftBarButtonItem and 2 rightBarButtonItems on all my ViewControllers.

UPDATED:

I noticed that this actually worked:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems;
```

But I still have to do this in every viewController, and thats not what I want.

---

Here is a general idea of what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: UINavigationController must have rootViewController. Just push some UIViewController in it.

Comment: the root view controller is already set on storyboard. The rootview is loading fine

Comment: Can you add your storyboard screenshot?

Comment: Its a little more complex than this, but this image should do it... its really just the navigationController and the viewController:
http://cl.ly/image/223K412t1M0F/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-21%20at%2011.40.29%20PM.png

Comment: Create a base view controller class. Write the code to set the bar buttons and their corresponding actions in this class. Create all other viewControllers as a subclass of the base view controller. This will automatically bring the navigation buttons in all classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GoGreen suggested, I created a base view controller with the corresponding buttons on the navigationItem.

Its not the simple solution I had in my mind but it works pretty good.